# Codeigniter Front End Controller Not working with libraries

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm posting this after my hair has been ripped out, ran out of rum, and tried everything I can find on google. I've been developing a site using codeigniter which makes use of templates.  I've built the backend first and all is working properly there.  So now i've started on getting the front end working which is where I'm hitting the issue.

I've created a controller called `pages.php` which is going to parse the uri string of the current page, use my library to get the page data from the database, then display it.  My pages are all created through an editor on the back end and stored in the database.

So here's the pages controller

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library("pages");
    }

    public function display_page()
    {
        $page_slug = $this->uri->segment(1);
        $data["joes"] = "Here's joes first variable";
        $this->pages->get_page($page_slug);
    }
}
```

and here's the error message i get when i hit my url like this `demo.mydomain.com/joes-test`

[image: ERROR MESSAGE]

and here is how my routes are set up. `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/display_page';`

My `Pages.php` library works perfect on the back end but it's a large file.  I've only posted the get_page function below.  If you need to see everything let me know.  But i dont believe the issue has anything to do with the library itself.

```
public function get_page($slug){
    $objPages = new pages();
    $objPages->get_object('slug="'.$slug.'"');
    return $objPages;
}
```

[EDIT] If i place the following inside my homepage controller it works.  But the calling function needs to be inside the library.

```
$this->load->library('pages');
$the_page = $this->pages->get_page("joes-test");
```

I want to call `$this->get_object("joes-test")` but this doesn't work. `get_object()` is an inherited function inside the library.

Now oddly enough. The code i put above will NOT work if i do the exact same thing inside the `pages` controller

any help leading to a solution would be awesome.  I'm under a time crunch and pay to get some assistance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the `pages` library class contain a constructor?

Comment: I'm wondering if this could be an example of CI's famous pickiness with capitalisation. Try renaming your pages.php library Pages.php.

Comment: @Utkanos if he's running CI 3 then the class name must begin with an upper case chara, since he said its working elsewhere, I'm thinking he may be overriding the  calling constructor in his library

Comment: I was referring to the library filename, not the class name.

Comment: Yes pages does contain a constructor and `parent::__construct()` inside of it.  And the library file is called `Pages.php` and the class inside is called `Pages` as well

Comment: You are in fact overriding the calling class' constructor, that line does not need to be in your library's constructor and typically libraries should not extend anything that's within the core of CI or you will run into issues like this one

Comment: I need it there because i am extending an abstract class, unless theres a way for me to run an initialize function without using the constructor, but that doesn't seem right to me.  Why would it work with an admin controller and not a front end controller?

Comment: Can you add the definition of your abstract class? Does it extend any of CI's stuff?

Comment: the abstract class doesn't extend any CI stuff.  Only manages objects and exposes helper functions as defaults

Comment: One example it would work with admin is if admin extends an CI extended class, example: `MY_Controller extends CI_controller`  and your front end controller does not

Comment: Both the front end and admin controllers are extending CI_Controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160213/discussion-between-kisaragi-and-joeb).

Comment: I removed the parent::constructor inside the pages library and it still has the same issue so it must be something else causing the issue.

Comment: There is something not shown in the provided code that is causing the issue. I suggest you find what is the difference between your admin section and your public section.

Comment: im willing to pay to have this resolved.

Comment: Wait wait... Couldn't it be because you have a controller names pages that is accessing a function via `$this->pages`... I'm not 100% sure how Ci handles the class scope but maybe it's thinking that `$this->pages` is referring to a function in the pages controller scope which obviously doesn't exist! Try renaming the controller and file just for giggles to test or something and see if it works. I can't think of any other reason why it would work in the backend and not the front end except for naming or collisions.

Comment: I could also be an idiot. I'm tired.

Comment: Could it because you have the same name for controller and library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't use the same name with controller and library. please choose another name. for example Mypages for you controller name.
change your routes

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'mypages/display_page';
```

then call your controller.

http://demo.mydomain.com/joes-test

Answer (score -1):

I think there nothing wrong with library uri, because as codeigniter official website say: `This class is initialized automatically by the system so there is no need to do it manually.`

I don't know about lib pages, but how about use

```
$this->load->view(<file-html>);
```

and if you want to passing data in variable, you can add variable like this

```
$this->load->view(<file-html>, $data);
```

Hope this help, Cheers

Comment: This answer doesn't seem related to the question